# How to add class to img_tag in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add class to `img_tag` in rails application.

```
<%= image_tag("user.png"), :class => "img-responsive" %>
```

Here i have added class img-responsive to the image.

but i am getting error if i add this statement in line.
i am not able to figure out what is missing in above line.

the error is:

```
app/views/pages/user_dashboard.html.erb:21: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the class attributes inside the bracket . Like `<%= image_tag("user.png", :class => "img-responsive") %>` Hope this will solve your problem . Have a great day

Answer (score 3):

Here is the optimized version:

```
<%= image_tag("user.png", class: "img-responsive", alt: "user image") %>
```